# Position TextBox Caret/Cursor to Same Line as Other Textbox C#

Tags: c#

I've been looking this up, but none of the methods I have tried worked.

I basically want to take the line the caret is on from one textbox, and scroll the second textbox to the same position.

This is what I tried:

```
        int line = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart);
        Point pNew = new Point();
        pNew.X = 0;
        pNew.Y = line;
        textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox2.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pNew);
        textBox2.ScrollToCaret();
```

All I want to do is keep the second textbox as scrolled as much as the first textbox.

Comment: I think `ScrollToCaret()` would need `Refresh()` later, and still would only work with focus on `textBox2`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :

```
       textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
       textBox2.ScrollToCaret();
```

this works where the two textboxes text are equal.

I didn't get your purpose of `All I want to do is keep the second textbox as scrolled as much as the first textbox.` I think: the two TextBoxes have the same Text.

Comment: That's my doubt too, is the goal to scroll to the same text or scroll to the same line as the other textBox? Also, do we want to scroll ScrollBars, so that same line is visible, or move caret as well?

Comment: No, the text of the two boxes are not equal.
Basically, I have two textboxes. They both contains different text, but I want when the user types in text in one of the textboxes that causes it to scroll, the text in the other textbox scrolls as well.

Comment: @user1432532 So the code does it.does the code worked for you ?